# Get id from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contains a case id.

Example strings:

```
[Case 123]
lorem[Case 123]ipsum
[Case 123]ipsum
```

I want to get the id (`123`) from the string.

I tried (on string `[Case 1359] needsmoreinfo`):

```
$pattern = '/[Case (\d+)]/';
preg_match($pattern, $message->subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Which resulted in:

```
o[0][0]: C
    [1]: 1
```

Not really what I was looking for :)

What should the pattern look like, or is there another flaw somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` and `]` are characters with special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape them to tell the regex engine to search for literal `[` and `]` characters:

```
$pattern = '/\[Case (\d+)\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $message->subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

See more on what these characters do when unescaped: regular expression [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to escape the opening square bracket:

```
$pattern = '/\[Case (\d+)]/';
```

It's otherwise interpreted as regex meta character which introduces a character class.

Comment: Aaargh damn. I should go to bed now. Thanks for pointing out the obvious! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the brackets. I mean doing `\[` and `\]`.
You should have:

```
$pattern = '/\[Case (\d+)\]/';
```